# React jsx files not rendering properly after being transformed offline

Tags: reactjs

My React jsx files were working fine with in-browser transformation.
But after I installed npm and installed react-tools, and did the transformation command line with `jsx -watch source/ build/`, the newly transformed JavaScript files looked fine, but would only render an incomplete DOM tree.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide more information. Besides, make sure you are using the JS file in `build` folder.

Comment: The JSX files were successfully transformed into JS files, which were then concatenated in their original order into one JS file , and I replaced the original more than 100 JSX files with the one concatenated JS file in index.jsp at the exact position where they were. I didn't touch anything else in index.jsp. However, the web page is not loading, showing an incomplete DOM tree, and Chrome's React debugger is only showing <Top Level></Top Level>, nothing else. And the $(document).ajaxSend() is not firing at all. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: you must have a problem with your minification / concat process.  You need to try just compiling them to single js files each with the react-tools and no minification and load those files and see if things work.  If so, as I suspect will be the case, you know it has to be the minification process somehow, so start tweaking it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark based on the info and I'm sure you moved on but...

In my case I was a bonehead and left `type="text/jsx"` in the script tag even though I was including the compiled js file, not jsx.  I just had to remove the type from the script tag and I was good to go.